# nginxproxymanager fail2ban for 401

Tags: fail2ban, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've setup nginxproxymanager and would like to use fail2ban for security. I'm very new to fail2ban need advise from y'all.

My access log when login failed as below

```
[12/Sep/2022:09:47:54 +0000] - 401 401 - POST http nginx.example.com "/api/tokens" [Client 192.168.X.XX] [Length 51] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.X.XX] "Mozilla/5.0...
[12/Sep/2022:11:11:32 +0000] - 401 401 - POST http nginx.example.com "/api/tokens" [Client 192.168.X.XX] [Length 51] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.X.XX] "Mozilla/5.0...
[12/Sep/2022:11:12:02 +0000] - 401 401 - POST http nginx.example.com "/api/tokens" [Client 192.168.X.XX] [Length 51] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.X.XX] "Mozilla/5.0...
[12/Sep/2022:11:12:43 +0000] - 401 401 - POST http nginx.example.com "/api/tokens" [Client 192.168.X.XX] [Length 51] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.X.XX] "Mozilla/5.0...
[12/Sep/2022:11:14:54 +0000] - 401 401 - POST http nginx.example.com "/api/tokens" [Client 192.168.X.XX] [Length 51] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.X.XX] "Mozilla/5.0...
[12/Sep/2022:11:15:26 +0000] - 401 401 - POST http nginx.example.com "/api/tokens" [Client 192.168.X.XX] [Length 51] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.X.XX] "Mozilla/5.0...
```

I really had no idea how to build the failregex, please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of jail that would find every 401 resulting attempt corresponding your log-format:

```ini
[nginxpm]
backend = auto
logpath = /path/to/log
filter =
failregex = ^\s*(?:\[\]\s+)?- 401 \d+ - [A-Z]+ \w+ \S+ "[^"]+" \[Client <ADDR>\]
enabled = true
```

If you need something more precise, for instance you can use `POST` instead of `[A-Z]+`, or `"/api/tokens\b[^"]*"` instead of `"[^"]+"` (then it would find only POST requests to `/api/tokens?...`.

> My access log when login failed as below

As for access-log, it is not advisable (due to possibly large parasite traffic) - better you'd configure nginx to log unauthorized attempts to another log-file and monitor it in the jail. Or may be monitor error-log instead.
See [fail2ban :: wiki :: Best practice # Reduce parasitic log-traffic](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice#reduce-parasitic-log-traffic) for details.